# how to run executable jar file on one machine from other machine

Tags: java, jar, remote-access, executable-jar, remote-server

I have a executable .jar file in a remote machine in windows environment. Now I want to execute this .jar file from other machine (windows environment) and need to open the console.

So far, I have shared the specific .jar file to everyone and created a .bat file in local machine with the below content.

```
@ECHO OFF

java -Xms512m -Xmx768m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=256m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dvendor=shell -DvendorFile="\\<REMOTE MACHINE'S IP>\WorkJars\servers_prod_remote.properties" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dyfs.logall=N -jar "\\<REMOTE MACHINE'S IP>\Users\tcs\Desktop\Status Compare\statuscompare4.jar"
```

It works fine for some machine, but for other machine, it fails and it prompts for the username and password of the remote machine.

Even if I try accessing the remote path from local using run command `\\<REMOTE MACHINE'S IP>\`, for some machine, it prompts for the username and passoword for security.

[Security Prompts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Q3t.png)

So whenever, I use .bat file from those local machine, it says "Access Denied".

Could anyone help me with this issue, as I don't want the username and password to be prompted and I just want to execute the .jar file without any issues.

Comment: This really sounds like a windows administration issue, rather than a java issue

Comment: I guess you can't do it (but you can do it in a programatical way). You have to login to the other machine to run the jar file (You may use remote desktop to loging to the other machine if the other machine is windows and you have proper access).

Answer (score 0):

If the jar file is excute on your machine, then the file is ok no issue with file.
Now your problem is it is not executing on some of the other machine not all. Its simple java need JRE to run or JDK for development.

Downlaod JRE **java runtime enviroment** from Oracle on the machine on which the file is not running and test it.

hope your problem is solve.

Another way is to quicky test if JRE is installed on the machine.

Open comand promte by clicking on start and type cmd. then type java - version

if it display some verison of java or something that means JRE is installed otherwise some other issue.

Comment: The problem is, from some machine, I'm not able to open \\<REMOTE MACHINE'S IP>, if I give it in Run command. Everytime it prompts for the username and password. But I've shared the folder completely to Everyone. But I don't know why its asking for the username and password again. So if I run the .bat file, it is not opening the .jar file, instead throws "Access Denied" error message.

Comment: give the username and password make it remember it will not ask next time.

Comment: I'm going to share this .bat file across all users. So I can't login each and every machine and make remember the username and password.